# How can i select all the html elements but not the first with css selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to select all the elements inside the `.container` excluding the `.Head` and all of its children (and children's children etc recursively).

Is there a way to get all the elements independent of their kinds? Something like a wildcard `*`

```
// I know, this is not valid. What is the element that I can replace the (*)
.container *:not(:first-child) select {
    background: yellow;
}
```

All items inside the red outline should be excluded from the selector. How can I do that?

```css
.container :not(:first-child) {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.Head {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="Head" style="border: 2px dashed red;">
    Target to exclude from the selector
    <div>Target to exclude</div>
    <div>Target to exclude</div>
  </div>
  <p>Target to select<p>
  <ul>
    <li>Target to select</li>
  </ul>
  <h1>Target to select</h1>
  <p class="anotherparagraph">Target to select</p>
  <span>Target to select</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, everything except .Head

Comment: So you want both the `ul` and the `li` to be selected too?

Comment: @ThisClark my question is different. I am selecting different kind of elements! @Lennholm Yes I want the `ul`, the `li`, and everything inside the `.container` excluding the `.Head` and the elements inside the `Head`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the "first" then, you just want to select everything except the element with a class and its children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.container > *:not(.Head), .container > *:not(.Head) * {  }
```

...should do it.

Comment: Wouldn't this be enough: `.container > *:not(.Head)`?

Comment: No, because of the child selector `>`, it won't select the descendants, which is apparently what the OP wants...

Answer (score 1):

You have to exclude the `.Head` class from the container in the CSS as in the example

```css
.container > :not(.Head){
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.Head {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="Head" style="border: 2px dashed red;">
    Target to exclude from the selector
    <div>Target to exclude</div>
    <div>Target to exclude</div>
  </div>
  <p>Target to select<p>
  <ul>
    <li>Target to select</li>
  </ul>
  <h1>Target to select</h1>
  <p class="anotherparagraph">Target to select</p>
  <span>Target to select</span>
</div>
```